# Success metric of database migration using row counts

Tags: data-analysis, feature-scaling, metric, databases

### Description

I have a problem where I'm tasked to successfully transform and repurpose data from one SQL server to another. Call the source $\text{src}$ and the target database $\text{tgt}$.

In order to assess the quality of the migration for a given field, I am given *volumes only*, namely

- $V_\text{src} = \#\{\text{rows in src for which property }P\text{ is true}\}$
- $V_\text{tgt} = \#\{\text{rows in tgt for which property }P\text{ is true}\}$

I was wondering if there was a set of metrics one often uses to report completion metrics from $0\%$ to $100\%$.
The metric should be 0 if the target is very dissimilar from source, and 100 if it is perfect similarity.

### An important side issue

Often you *overshoot* and you have $V_\text{src} \ll V_\text{tgt}$, so just reporting ratios yields that $\text{tgt}$ has $270\%$ more content than $\text{src}$.

In these situations **I would like to assign property P a low score near 0**, but not a negative score.

### Approach

For now I have for a given error coefficient $\varepsilon$ that's (mostly) $-1\leq \varepsilon \leq 1$ (but can overshoot to values close to 2 or 3) the following rescaling functions:

$$\text{invLin}(\varepsilon) = \dfrac{1}{1+\varepsilon}\qquad {\color{blue}\checkmark}\quad\text{slow decrease from }100\%\text{ to }0\%$$
However it gives huge error percentages like $500\%$ a high grade and doesn't penalize low error percentages enough to my taste.
I came up with this second one:

$$\text{invLog}(\varepsilon) = 1-\log^{+}(1+\varepsilon)\qquad {\color{blue}\checkmark}\quad\text{quick decrease from }100\%\text{ to }0\%$$

You can see the two functions plotted for values of $100\lvert\varepsilon\rvert$ ranging from $0\%$ to $500\%$ with a zoom on the $1-100$ zone on the left part

Notation: $f^+$ is the positive part of a function $f^+(x)=\max(f(x),0)$

[image: Rescaling attempt]

### Addendum (Sample data)

I was told it was easier to guess with some sample data, here's an example:

| Condition $P$ | $V_{\text{src}}$ | $V_{\text{src}}$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sum Expected Amount (\$) | 1543385231 | 1543385217,9 |
| Sum Commited Amount (\$) | 83123640,62 | 83123640,62 |
| Sum Real Amount (\$) | 1246623860,05 | 203779813,48 |
| Sum Amount for Region 1 (\$) | 4898 | 26712 |
| Sum Amount for Region 2 (\$) | 205509 | 93393 |
| Sum Amount for Region 3 (\$) | 3818 | 1667 |
| Number of users with unlimited rights | 412390 | 1286545 |
| Number of users with limited rights | 100286613 | 376796 |
| Number of shared costs | 402 | 222 |
| Number of items created between 2019-2030 | 4 | 4 |
| Number of items created between 2020-2023 | 260 | 260 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you?

$$100 \times \bigg(1 - \frac{|V_{src} - V_{tgt}|}{V_{src} + V_{tgt}}\bigg)$$

The fraction part is the ratio of the absolute difference in values to the combined total, which gives $0$ if the values are the same and near $1$ if one value is $0$ and the other $>0$. This is then adjusted so a match is $1$ and and a big difference is near $0$ and scaled to the range $0 - 100$.

For example, for your "Number of users with unlimited rights" this gives:

$$100 \times \bigg(1 - \frac{|412390 - 1286545|}{412390 + 1286545}\bigg) = 48.55$$

and for "Number of users with limited rights" this gives:

$$100 \times \bigg(1 - \frac{|100286613 - 376796|}{100286613 + 376796}\bigg) = 0.75$$

Comment: This is a very simple yet very good answer, I will wait for a bit to see if others have more original/niche metrics :)